# Остановить зацикленное воспроизведение скрипта с помощью "clearInterval()"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт счетчика на сайте. Счетчик ведет последовательный обратный отсчет от "9" до "2" с заданной скоростью "speed". Надо сделать так, чтобы после достижения последнего значения ("2") счетчик останавливался. Сейчас счетчик после достижения "2" опять переходит к "9" и начинает обратный отсчет заново, т.е. счетчик зациклен. Знаю, что для этого есть функция `clearInterval()`, но не знаю, куда эту функцию нужно вставить в код.

HTML:

```
<ul id="copy1">
    <li style="display: list-item;">9</li>
    <li style="display: none;">8</li>
    <li style="display: none;">7</li>
    <li style="display: none;">6</li>
    <li style="display: none;">5</li>
    <li style="display: none;">4</li>
    <li style="display: none;">3</li>
    <li style="display: none;">2</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.list_ticker = function (options) {

        var defaults = {
            speed: 4000,
            effect: 'slide'
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var obj = $(this);
            var list = obj.children();
            list.not(':first').hide();

            setInterval(function () {

                list = obj.children();
                list.not(':first').hide();

                var first_li = list.eq(0)
                var second_li = list.eq(1)

                if (options.effect == 'slide') {
                    first_li.slideUp();
                    second_li.slideDown(function () {
                        first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);
                    });
                } else if (options.effect == 'fade') {
                    first_li.fadeOut(function () {
                        second_li.fadeIn();
                        first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);
                    });
                }
            }, options.speed)
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#copy1').list_ticker({
        speed: 60000,
        effect: 'fade'
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея в том, чтобы завести счетчик совершенных итераций (`counter`) и сохранить в переменной ID, возвращаемый функцией `setInterval` (`intervalId`). После чего при достижении счетчиком определённого значения остановить интервал с помощью `clearInterval(intervalId)`.

Часть кода, которую нужно изменить:

```
var counter = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {

    list = obj.children();
    list.not(':first').hide();

    var first_li = list.eq(0)
    var second_li = list.eq(1)

    if (options.effect == 'slide') {
        first_li.slideUp();
        second_li.slideDown(function () {
            first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);
        });
    } else if (options.effect == 'fade') {
        first_li.fadeOut(function () {
            second_li.fadeIn();
            first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);
        });
    }
    counter++;
    if (counter == list.length - 1) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, options.speed)
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu0upk7c/).

Comment: спасибо за код. Всё работает как нужно. Извиняюсь за мое корявое изложение проблемы. И благодарю за ваше терпение и помощь.

Comment: @Егор на здоровье :)

Answer (score 1):

Надо сохранить счетчик вот таким образом:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  \\...
```

Не известно мне, по вашим вопросом, где в скрипте хотите остановить счетчик, но, в любом случае, когда хотите остановить его, то надо вот так:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Счетчик остановился. Но возникла другая проблема: счетчик остановился после одной итерации, т.е. "9" поменял на "8" и всё. А мне нужно, чтобы счетчик сработал ещё 7 раз и дошел до цифры "2" и потом остановился на этой цифре. Можете помочь с этим вопросом?